# Module (nodemon) not found(package.json not found) DOCKER ISSUE

Tags: express, docker, nodemon

i'm trying to dockerize my express app, but when i try to run the CMD in the container , docker says me ' "Command \"nodemon\" not found."' like it doesn't find package.json in container. This is my dockerfile:

```
FROM node:8
WORKDIR /express-app/

COPY package.json .

RUN yarn

COPY . .

ARG MONGO_DB_DATABASE
ENV MONGO_DB_DATABASE ${MONGO_DB_DATABASE}
ARG MONGO_DB_USERNAME
ENV MONGO_DB_USERNAME ${MONGO_DB_USERNAME}
ARG MONGO_DB_PASSWORD
ENV MONGO_DB_PASSWORD ${MONGO_DB_PASSWORD}

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

and this is my docker-compose.yml

```
express-app:
build: ../../express-app
command:nodemon
environment:
  - MONGO_DB_DATABASE=testDb
  - MONGO_DB_USERNAME=test
  - MONGO_DB_PASSWORD=test
expose:
  - 3000
ports:
  - "3000:3000"
volumes:
  - ../../express-app:/express-app
depends_on:
  - mongodb
links:
  - mongodb
restart: always
```

Answer (score -1):

Somewhere in your `Dockerfile`, throw in a `RUN npm install nodemon -g`. That installs and adds to your path

Comment: Does it change the error you get? Is it finding `nodemon`?

Comment: The problem is that there isn't package.json in the container